# Program to continuously check availability of internet connection c#

Tags: c#, networking, status-monitoring

I have a C# program to check if a hard coded host is available and if not, waits then checks again (this is a loop in form of recursion). How can it be enhanced?

```
using System;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace trial17
{
    public partial class Form5 : Form
    {
        public Form5()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        static Ping p = new Ping();
        static string host = "8.8.8.8";
        static byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
        static int timeout = 1000;
        static PingOptions po = new PingOptions();
        static PingReply pr;
        static bool load = false;
//plays media if connected        
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer("media file path");

        private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Show();
                conn();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        async void conn()
        {
            try
            {
                pr = p.Send(host, timeout, buffer, po);
                if (pr.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    player.Play();
//label updated after connection
                    label1.Text = "Connected";
                }
                else
                {
                    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(200);
                    conn();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to avoid using recursion on `conn`. Say you did not have internet connection for a long time. Then, for every failed connection you will add a new entry to the call stack. Which could eventually lead to a stack overflow.

It's probably a better idea to have two methods. Something along the lines of:

```cs
// Ignoring exception handling for sake of simplicity
bool checkConnection()
{
  pr = p.Send(host, timeout, buffer, po);
  return pr.Status == IPStatus.Success;
}

async void connectionTask()
{
  while (!checkConnection())
  {
    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(200);
  }
  player.Play();
  //label updated after connection
  label1.Text = "Connected";
}
```

Comment: Is the ```Task.Delay()``` method capable of causing a Stack Overflow? And how long should my optimal delay time in ms be?

Comment: avoid `async void`.

Comment: @aepot I tried running this program for 10 minutes and it caused a BSOD with an error regarding unchecked kernel. What happened?

Comment: @user14773854 C# can't cause OS kernel fault because it's managed code. Probably there's some drivers or hardware issue.